# Is it possible to use Seam in a JBoss timed service?

Tags: java, service, jboss, seam

I've started to write some new JBoss timed service that was meant to use some existing seam components. But it seems that I can't access these components because of non-existing contexts. Is it possible to use them other than in the typical situation with JSF?

A little snippet to demonstrate what I want to do...

```
@Service
public class MyService extends DefaultTimedService implements TimedObject, DefaultServiceInterface {
    @Timeout
    public void ejbTimeout(Timer timer) {
        MyInterface loader = (MyInterface) Component.getInstance(MyInterface.SEAM_NAME, true);
        // throws no context!
    }
}
```

That throws the following exception for example:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No application context active
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.forName(Component.java:1945)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2005)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is one way that is a little dirty and there are many developers that would not use such a hack ever but it will solve your problem:

```
import org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle;

@Service
public class MyService extends DefaultTimedService implements TimedObject, DefaultServiceInterface {
    @Timeout
    public void ejbTimeout(Timer timer) {
        Lifecycle.beginCall();

        MyInterface loader = (MyInterface) Component.getInstance(MyInterface.SEAM_NAME, true);
        // will not throw no context!
        // also the Component.getInstance(MyInterface.SEAM_NAME, true,true); call
        // is another way you could inject that component. 

        Lifecycle.endCall();
    }
}
```

I have used it in one project where I couldn't find anything else that worked. If anybody has another solution I am looking forward to seeing it here :).

Comment: Thanks too... I'll give it a try... looks dirty but promissing :)

Comment: The beginCall() did the basics... well. Now I have to solve some other pre-conditions to get my components to work. Thanks!

Comment: One more hint here... beginCall() does not start a transaction and all EntityManager operations fail quietly. If using beginCall() und endCall() it is mandatory to handle the transaction too! By using Transaction.instance().begin() and Transaction.instance().commit() I could get it to actually do something real.

Answer (score 1):

What scope have you defined for the component? Probably application context as it says so in the error.

...

So I poked around the source and found out that contexts are stored in a class named [Contexts](http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/seam/trunk/src/main/java/org/jboss/seam/contexts/Contexts.java). All contexts seems to be thread specific, because they are encapsulated in [ThreadLocal-instances](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html). That means that has to specified for thread of the timed service...

The question remains though: how do create a context for a specific thread.

Comment: The one I want to use has SESSION Scope defined... I could switch to CONVERSATION if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you inject the `loader` instance, instead of of locating it with that static call? I'm not quite familiar with Seam, but perhaps (in the class body):

```
@In private MyInterface loader;
```

and then, in your method, just use the `loader`.

As it seems, Seam has the application /statelesss scopes, which seems the appropriate one in your case:

```
@Scope(ScopeType.APPLICATION)
```

or

```
@Scope(ScopeType.STATELESS)
```

Try one of those - since your class doesn't seem to need any information from the session/request, it's more appropriate not to use a web-related scope.

So define `MyService` and `MyInterface` in one of the above scopes, and try both injection and your lookup method.

Check the [Seam tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/1.2.1.GA/reference/en/html/concepts.html) on contexts and concurrency

[This thread](http://seamframework.org/Community/NoApplicationContextActiveInJavalangThread) seems helpful.

[And from this thread](http://seamframework.org/Community/NoActiveApplicationContext) it seems there is an `@Asynchronous` annotation, that you might use.

Comment: No, I can't. Injection has the same problem as with trying to access the component as described above... the context is missing. Injection only works in specific types and is normally performed during the request/response lifecycle.

Comment: injection works depending on scope. the request/response lifecycle is about converstation/session/request scopes. There are others.

Comment: But the JBoss service isn't touched by the injection inspectors... it initializes during server startup. Is it possible to solve this?
- ahh... just recognized your edit... will give it a try.

Comment: Simply adding @Scope to the service doesn't have any impact. The exceptions remains the same. So I added @Name too and now Seam recognizes the service as a component. But the running service (in its own thread) doesn't seem to live in any Seam context... the exception remains the same here too.

Comment: I added some links to my answer, check them

Comment: I will... give me two days - we are very busy at the moment.

Comment: sure. just mention when you try it, what was the outcome