# SEAM: How to get EntityManager and Logger in a class that is loaded dynamically?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, seam, entitymanager

I have a background service that runs every 10 min.

This service queries the DB for jobs to execute a will load a class with a different business logic according to the job (using Class.forName()). They implement the same Interface, of course.

I declared those classes to be SEAM components but when I try to use the entityManager or Logger I get a NPE.

Answering my own question, I suppose this is because Class.forName() goes under SEAM's injection mechanism and it won't have a chance to inject the dependencies.

I could probably work around that by injecting those myself, after I load the class. Is there a better way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you check how to use [EJB-Timer Service](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.1.GA/reference/en-US/html/jms.html)?

Another resource:

[Is it possible to use Seam in a JBoss timed service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070262/is-it-possible-to-use-seam-in-a-jboss-timed-service)

I have to do something similar in a few days.

Please leave a comment what worked for you ;-)

Comment: I'm using the EJB 3 timers. Strangely enough I haven't had the 'No context' problem mentioned in the other question. Loading the component using Component.getInstance(String, boolean) solved the issue for me, no need to call lyfecicle.beginCall()... Anyway, now I'm able to use the EntityManager and Logger. Thanks!

Comment: @Cleber Goncalves Thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can inject all Seam components in non seam classes by using

```
Component.getInstance("entityManager") //You can inject whatever you want.
```

To get the Logger working you can do the following

```
 private static final LogProvider log = Logging.getLogProvider(MyClass.class);
```